# I have portfolio volatility for year 1 and for year 2. What is portfolio volatility for year 1 and 2 combined?

Tags: volatility, portfolio, time

Thanks for looking into this question.

Portfolio volatility in year 1 = 15%.
Portfolio volatility in year 2 = 20%.

What is the portfolio volatility over the timespan year 1 and 2 combined?

Is it SQRT(0.5)*15% + SQRT(0.5)*20%?

Thanks!

Comment: Letting $X_i$ represent rate at year $i$ and remember rate from year 1 to year 2 would be $(1+X_1)(1+X_2)-1=X_1X_2+X_1+X_2$ (if compounded meaning you reinvested all of your earnings and original amount at from year 1). Thus want to find $Var(X_1X_2+X_1+X_2)$ Now if we assume that rates from year one to year to are independent and note that $X_1X_2$ is normally quite a small number we would have $Var(X_1X_2+X_1+X_2)\approx Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)$

Comment: I would like to note I don't know if this is necessarily true but what I think is if anyone knows my analysis is wrong please correct me

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful please upvote and accept one of them. I have noticed that you haven't cast a single vote since you joined. Feedback is very valuable for the community - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we are talking about [volatility as the standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(finance)#Mathematical_definition) of uncorrelated random variables (in this case this would mean no autocorrelation) the [variance is additive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29), which means that we get $\sqrt{.15^2+.2^2}=.25=25\%$.

You can illustrate this result by simulation in R:

```
> sd(rnorm(1e7,sd=.15)+rnorm(1e7,sd=.2))
[1] 0.2500001
```

If you want to annualize this number again you'd have to divide by $\sqrt{2}$ (because of the two one-year periods) which gives about $17.68\%$.

So putting it all together what you do is to calculate the square root of the average of the squared volatilities: $$\sqrt{\frac{.15^2+.2^2}{2}}\approx.1768=17.68\%$$.

This can again be illustrated by a simulation in R:

```
> sd(c(rnorm(1e7,sd=.15),rnorm(1e7,sd=.2)))
[1] 0.1767796
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have the vol of the first half and second half of the return series.
Assume mean of returns are zero:

Vol of first year and second year:
$$
 \sigma1^2 = sum(R_1i^2)/openDaysYear1;   
$$
$$
 \sigma2^2 = sum(R_2i^2)/openDaysYear2;    
$$

Vol of the entire series:
$$
\sigma^2 = sum(R_i^2)/nbDaysInTwoYears 
$$
$$
         = (\sigma1^2 *openDaysYear1 + \sigma2^2 * openDaysYear2)/(openDaysYear1 +openDaysYear2)
$$

Comment: Thanks, but what if I also have the return data? Does that change the calculation (then I don't have to assume the mean is zero).
I've tested this on data from Apple on 2013 and 2014, but I get a different volatility when I calculate it at once based on the returns for the whole 2-year period and when I calculate it based upon the volatily in year and in year 2 (via the method in your answer).

Comment: =STDEV(returns from 2013)*SQRT(252 trading days) = volatility of 28.9% |||||  =STDEV(returns from 2014)*SQRT(252 trading days) = volatility of 21.7% ||||| =STDEV(returns from 2013 and 2014)*SQRT(504 trading days) = volatility of 36.1% ||||| (28.9% * 252 + 21.7% * 252)/(252+252) = 25.2%

Comment: If the mean return is not zero the formula of course has to take them into account - probably for the case of aapl.